# spring authentication for rest api to include hardcoded and lookup

Tags: spring, rest, authentication, spring-security

I have a rest API application that authenticates requests by verifying credentials with a database lookup. I need to now add an additional feature that will allow a specific set of credentials to be allowed that is not a record in the database table. Basically I need to hardcode these credentials; but what I found is that the spring authenticationprovider for userDetails does not authenticate this and I am not sure why or how. I added an if statement just before retrieving the dataset result to validate the user credentials but it still does not work.Here is my code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException 
{

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.reader.AuthService.loadUserByUsername");   

logger.info("Request--");

UserDetails userDt = null;

logger.info("USER:" + username);


Connection con = null; 
String query = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE username= ?";

logger.info("Making SQL request");

try
{
    con= dataSource.getConnection();
    String password = null;
    String authority = null;
    int enabled = 0;

    try(Connection dbConn = dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement pst = dbConn.prepareStatement(query);)
    {



        pst.setString(1, username);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if(username.equalsIgnoreCase("sampleUser")){
            username = "sampleUser";
            password="1234567_sample";
            List ls = new ArrayList();
            ls.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER"));
            userDt = new User(username, password, enabled==1?true:false , true, true, true, ls);
            return userDt;
        }

        if (rs.next())
        {
            username = rs.getString("username");
            password = rs.getString("password");    

            authority = "ROLE_USER";
            enabled = rs.getInt("isactive");
            List ls = new ArrayList();
            ls.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(authority));
            userDt = new User(username, password, enabled==1?true:false , true, true, true, ls);
        }               
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No credentials present in DB for username" + username);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                    "Bad Credentials", username);       
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {   
        System.out.println("API: "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    con.close();
}

catch(UsernameNotFoundException e)
{
    throw e;
}   
catch(Exception e1)
{
    e1.printStackTrace();
}


return userDt;
```

In the server-context file I declare the user ref service to this class file above:

```
    <beans:bean id="authservice"
    class="com.reader.security.AuthService" />

    <security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="authservice" />
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

I think the problem starts here in AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider:

```
try {
        preAuthenticationChecks.check(user);
        additionalAuthenticationChecks(user, (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication);
    } catch (AuthenticationException exception) {
        if (cacheWasUsed) {
            // There was a problem, so try again after checking
            // we're using latest data (i.e. not from the cache)
            cacheWasUsed = false;
            user = retrieveUser(username, (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication);
            preAuthenticationChecks.check(user);
            additionalAuthenticationChecks(user, (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication);
        } else {
            throw exception;
        }
    }
```

here is the exception:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException: User is disabled
```

could someone please assist or at least explain how this authentication works.

EDIT:

console response:

```
10:29:04.703 [http-nio-8080-exec-2]  
DEBUG  o.s.s.w.a.w.BasicAuthenticationFilter - Basic 
Authentication Authorization header found for user 
'internalUser'
10:29:04.705 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] 
DEBUG o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt 
using   org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.
DaoAuthenticationProvider
10:29:04.707 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  
c.b.f.AuthService.loadUserByUsername - Request--
10:29:04.707 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  
c.b.f.AuthService.loadUserByUsername - USER:internalUser
10:29:04.707 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  
c.b.f.AuthService.loadUserByUsername - Making SQL request
AbandonedObjectPool is 
used   (org.apache.commons.dbcp.AbandonedObjectPool@3517a554)
LogAbandoned: false
RemoveAbandoned: true
RemoveAbandonedTimeout: 300
10:32:51.434 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] 
DEBUG o.s.s.a.d.DaoAuthenticationProvider - User account is disabled
10:37:12.083 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] 
DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached 
instance of singleton 
bean 'userAuthenticationErrorHandler'
10:37:12.083 [http-nio-8080-exec-2]
DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance 
of singleton bean   'org.springframework.context.annotation.
internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor'
```

Comment: Kindly add the entire stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your code is setting enabled as false as you initialized enabled integer to zero and later below  **enabled==1?true:false**  which will always return false. So i think you missed to set enabled = 1 in case of your "sampleUser" inside if statement

int enabled = 0;

```
if(username.equalsIgnoreCase("sampleUser")){
        username = "sampleUser";
        password="1234567_sample";
        List ls = new ArrayList();
        ls.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER"));
        userDt = new User(username, password, enabled==1?true:false , true, true, true, ls);
        return userDt;
    }
```

Comment: bless you. Yes that was it and not sure how I missed that. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

`loadUserByUsername(String username)` gets called when authentication is completed

for authentication purpose you need to override `authenticate()` and use it as given below

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserService userService;

    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
          String username = authentication.getName();
          String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

            CustomUser user = userService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (user == null || !user.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase(username)) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Username not found.");
            }

            if (!password.equals(user.getPassword())) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Wrong password.");
            }

            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getAuthorities();

            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, authorities);
    }

    public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

and declare it in security xml

```
<authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </authentication-manager>
```

Comment: appreciate your response but found Anudeep to have found my error. Thanks